# Java Regex - Alphabet + numbers with minimum total of 3

Tags: java, regex

### What have I been doing so far?

I have been searching on internet for a full hour now, but I just can't seem to find it, most answers are based on just alphabetic characters or only digits. I'm a beginner with regex and I'm trying to learn it but I just don't get it why this wouldn't work.

### The problem

What I want is that (for a search machine) the input is validated with a pattern. This pattern must consist out of a minimum combination of 3 letters and or numbers. Special characters are allowed as well but there must be at least a total of 3 letters or numbers in the input.

### What have I tried?

I tried using `(([aA-zZ]{0,}[0-9]{0,}){3,})\w+` But this doesn't allow special characters nor does it get that I want 3 subsequential characters, because 2 are also allowed

### So what would be correct and what would be incorrect?

asdA - **correct** - more than three in a row

as   - **incorrect** - less than three in a row

a1s - **correct** - three in a row

+a1s/ **correct** - three in a row

+a1-s -**incorrect** - less than 3 in a row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to validate 3 consecutive letter or numbers then use this regex:

```
[A-Za-z0-9]{3}
```

In java use:

```
str.matches(".*[A-Za-z0-9]{3}.*");
```

Comment: Ah I tested this answer without the `.*` works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like:

```
 System.out.println("asdA".matches(".*?[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}.*?"));
 System.out.println("as".matches(".*?[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}.*?"));
 System.out.println("a1s".matches(".*?[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}.*?"));
 System.out.println("+a1s/".matches(".*?[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}.*?"));
 System.out.println("+a1-s".matches(".*?[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}.*?"));
```

Comment: this pattern almost completely answers my question, I had to add a , after 3 but it doesn't seem to include any trailing special character

Comment: You wont need a "," it would be covered by any number of characters after 3 contiguous 3 characters containing alphabets or numbers or combinations. What pattern were you after?

Comment: ah ofcourse I understand, but for some reason the accepted answer also validate the trailing special characters while yours wouldn't (using [Regexr](http://www.regexr.com) )

Comment: Ah I learned this was caused because the '?' is 'lazy' so it won't match the special character

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work for you:

```
\w*([a-zA-Z0-9]){3,}\w*
```